# Выполнение js после его подгрузки в html

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
У меня скрипт через ajax подгружает html контент . В данный html я добавил js функцию новую с button-ом.

Можно ли как-то заставить работать данную функцию ?

пример :

```
var text='<script>function test(){alert("test");}</script><button onclick="test();">test</button>';
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Во-первых ты его не туда вставляешь, тебе надо его в `body` вложить  `document.body.innerHTML = text;`, но и так он у тебя не видит саму функцию `test`.  Честно не знаю, колдовал с примером твои час, так и не понял... Дождусь ответа более опытных колег

Answer (score 0):

Нет смысла динамически добавлять тег `<script>`, код внутри него уже не будет выполнен.

```js
//Этот блок будет вызван только после загрузки документа
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    //Так можно добавить новую глобальную функцию
    window.test = function(){alert("test");};
    
    var html='<button onclick="test();">test</button>';
    //Используем pure js современный селектор
    var text = document.querySelector('#text');
    
    text.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<h3>Пример</h3>
<div id="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Код скрипта нужно запустить после вставки. Вот на jQuery пример:

```
$("#text").find("script").each(function(i) {
eval($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать jQuery в каждом "HelloWorld".